# Display a friendly looking default elevation prompt for programs created with visual studio C# 2008 on Win7

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2008, build, compiler-warnings, elevated-privileges

When I create a program in Visual Studio 2008 C# on Windows 7 and compile it to an Executable I have often to include a manifest to make the program asking for administrator permissions.
When I do this and build the Executable with a manifest it doesn't display a "friendly" elevation prompt but a yellow-orange one with a warning exclamation mark. 
If I choose "run as administrator" for any usual tool done by Microsoft or another programmer it displays me a "friendly" blue-green dialog which notes me that the program needs administrator permissions. On my personal programs appear these yellow-orange "warning-alike" dialogs.
How do I exchange this orange dialog with the good green-blue looking one?

I am a novice, so I would appreciate a step-by-step instruction on how to do this.